# Exclude Externals from jsDoc output

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

How can we exclude `Externals` section from jsDoc output correctly?

I have lots of externals in my project that I do not want to show on the navigation panel at all, as it takes up all the space, and is useless to us.

I have been able to hack it manually, by changing the code in file `node_modules\jsdoc\lib\util\templateHelper.js`, but this is not a reusable approach for my team of developers.

The hack was in overriding `members.externals` with an empty array:

```
/*
    members.externals = members.externals.map(function(doclet) {
        doclet.name = doclet.name.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
        return doclet;
    });
*/
    members.externals = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, after years of using `jsDoc`, all I can do is to continue re-hacking it after every update of the dependency, in file `node_modules\jsdoc\lib\util\templateHelper.js`.

Fortunately, even with the current version 3.5.5, the hack still works the same:

```
// HACK: set Externals to an empty list:
members.externals = []; /*members.externals.map(function(doclet) {
    doclet.name = doclet.name.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');

    return doclet;
});*/
```

Comment: I'm now using this hack as well. Definitely not satisfying. How do you handle external modules that do not define themselves? I had to go in and hack the modules with @external, which is even less satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is much more elegant, but this is what I ended up doing. It works for all projects without having to hack the jsdoc install.

My problem: I have classes derived from imported node_modules and I wanted the inherited information included in my documentation, but I didn't want the base classes clogging up the sidebar navigation.

First, I added a plugin to my jsdoc-template (I called it skip-node_modules):

```
exports.handlers = {
    processingComplete: function (e)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < e.doclets.length; i++)
        {
            const doclet = e.doclets[i]
            if (!doclet.undocumented && doclet.meta && doclet.meta.path.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1)
            {
                // hack the name so I can find it in the .tmpl file
                // I tried to add a new flag to the doclet, but it didn't pass through
                doclet.longname += '~'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then I added a check in the navigation.tmpl:

```
<ul class="list">
<?js
this.nav.forEach(function (item) {
?>
    <?js if (item.longname[item.longname.length - 1] !== '~') { ?>
    <li class="item" data-name="<?js= item.longname ?>">
    ...
    <? } ?>
```

And poof, no more node_module imports in my sidebar. (This does have the downside of not showing a sidebar when you click through to these classes. I'm sure with more hacking I can get rid of that, but it wasn't too important.)

It would be easy to change this to check for external symbols. console.log(e) in the plugin to get all the info the doclets provide and find what works for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by creating a custom site template and customizing our JSDoc `publish.js` file.

1. You will need to copy the `default` template directory from `node_modules/jsdoc/templates/` to whatever directory contains your documentation and rename it to something you will remember/unique; for this example we will use `site_template`.
2. Locate the `publish.js` file in the `site_template` directory, inside of this file you may comment-out/remove the following line located inside of the `buildNav` function: `nav += buildMemberNav(members.externals, 'Externals', seen, linktoExternal);`
3. Customize your `jsdoc.config.js` file, under the `"opts"` attribute add the following attribute `"template":"RELATIVE_PATH_TO_YOUR_DOCS/site_template"`

When building your docs the Externals navigation section will now be omitted.

This method should also prevent you

If you need further references here are the links from JsDoc related to this

- [JSDoc | Configuring JSDoc's default template](https://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-default-template.html)
- [JSDoc | Configuring JSDoc with a configuration file](https://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-jsdoc.html)